# Basic Authentication programmatically

Tags: asp.net, basic-authentication

I need to lock down a wcf service with basic authentication and SSL. However it is on shared hosting who won't enable it for me. Is there a way of mimicing basic authentication in code with just code that would likely work in a shared environment? I want SharePoint Online to read this wcf service and apparently it presents credentials as basic.

Comment: I think you have to embed the security in the web service itself using a ticket-issuing approach, but not 100% sure if that's the only option.

Answer (score 1):

You probably will not be able to get this done with your shared hosting service.  SSL requires a registered domain name to associate with the keys.  Your hosting service should offer a dedicated site with SSL, shop around for the best price.